# Automatic foreign key index creation with GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Indexes for foreign keys were created automatically in older Grails versions (e.g. 1.3.x or 2.2.x).
In newer Grails versions the DB indexes are no longer created automatically for foreign keys. I have tested it with Grails 2.5 and Grails 3 on MySQL. 
Is it possible to enable this feature in the newer Grails versions by some configuration or anything other?